# What is the origin of ゟ (より)?

Tags: etymology, orthography, hiragana, calligraphy

`ゟ` is a digraph that is read より. Where does it originate from?

Is it a ligature, like `& <- et`, or German `ß <- ſs -> ss`? (Wikipedia claims this, citing no source.) Also, if it *is* a ligature, what did the ligation process look like (e.g. what are the intermediate forms between `より` and `ゟ`)?

Alternatively, could it be a derivative of `与` or another kanji? (Another non-authoritative source which I have now lost track of claims this.)

Comment: I think it's quite clearly a ligature of よ and り – don't forget that this is from the period when Japanese was written vertically.

Comment: BTW, よ is derived from 与 and り from 利.  This is general knowledge, so I don't have a source, though :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are quite a few old (17th century) letters on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924092851/http://tor.jp/komonjo/collection.html) which use the digraph ゟ as ligature of よ and り. For example see the fifth line from the left of the following letter, which reads 「家来之者方ゟ可申」.

[image: ゟ]

As @ZhenLin points out, it is not too far a stretch of your imagination that ゟ comes from joining よ and り in vertical writing. All that is really lost is the loop of the よ.

Comment: Could you point out where ゟ appears on that page? I'm not very good at reading calligraphic Japanese.

Comment: @senshin:  It is third character from the bottom of the fifth line from the left.  `家来之者方ゟ可申`